# Javascript get Selected Value returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website, with the following code in an `.aspx` page.

```
<form action="#" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
    <select id="SelectEquipmentDropdown">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When this renders in HTML, I get the following

```
<form action="#" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
                        <select id="SelectEquipmentDropdown">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
```

And on my HTML page, I see this

[image]

When I use this javascript to return the `selectedValue` of the option, **I get the value `undefined` returning**. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong???

```
var e = document.getElementById("SelectEquipmentDropdown");
var selectedEquipmentDropdown = e.options[e.selectedIndex].Value;
```

Comment: Try `e.value` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Value` should be`.value` see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lddyn573/9/

```
<form action="#" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
  <select id="SelectEquipmentDropdown" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var e = document.getElementById("SelectEquipmentDropdown");
var selectedEquipmentDropdown = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;//change it here

alert(selectedEquipmentDropdown);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! I knew it had to be something simple! Argh... case sensitivity continues to trip me up! :)) Thanks